# adding all possible connections between dots in r plot

Tags: r, plot

I have data-frame DOTS with following columns: DOT, X, Y. There are 10 dots.

I want to display all possible connections: (a) between dots 1,2,3,4,5; (b) 5,6,7; and (c) between 7,8,9,10?

```
# what I tried so far

plot(DOTS$X, DOTS$Y, main= "DOTS", xlab= "X", ylab= "Y",
col= "blue", pch = 19, cex = 1, lty = "solid", lwd = 2)

text(DOTS$X, DOTS$Y, labels=DOTS$Dot, cex= 0.7, pos = 3)

lines(DOTS$X,DOTS$Y)

# the last line displays connection from 1 to 2 to 3 etc only
```

Thank you in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: I suggest you [edit] your question to construct a dataset. (The `combn` function might be of some use.)

Comment: Did you mean to have overlapping groups - 1-to-5, 5-to-7, 7-to-10?

Comment: yes. 1-5 connected to each other and only 5 will have a connection to 6-7; then 5-7 connected to each other and only 7 will have a connection to 8-10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I make a dataset first :

```
x <- runif(10, 0, 10)
y <- runif(10, 0, 10)
df <- data.frame(dot = LETTERS[1:10], x = x, y = y)
```

I think it's flexible to create a custom function and use `combn()` to generate all possible combinations of two dots. And then connect them with `segments()` respectively. In the custom function below, you can put any dots set and arguments e.g. `col`, `lwd`... etc.

```
plot(df$x, df$y)
text(df$x, df$y, labels = df$dot, pos = 3)

line.fun <- function(index, ...){
  comb <- combn(index, 2)
  start <- comb[1, ] # starting points
  end <- comb[2, ]   # end points
  segments(df$x[start], df$y[start], df$x[end], df$y[end], ...)
}

line.fun(1:5, col = 2)
line.fun(5:7, col = 3)
line.fun(7:10, col = 4)
```

[image]